# A Linear Algebra Problem

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I am looking for 
a symmetric matrix $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that

$$
S A + A^T S = I
$$

$A$ can be assumed to be regular (with positive determinant, if this is of any help).

The difficulty is of course that $S$ must be symmetric, otherwise one could simply take $2S = A^{-T}$. In principle this is a linear equation with $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ unknowns and this can be solved for $S$.

Is there a nicer way to find $S$ such as a closed solution formula using some factorization? Has this problem been studied anywhere?

Comment: Do you already know (and is it true at all) that the system of linear equations is uniquely solvable? 

Comment: Yes, this follows from geometric considerations (which are a bit too lengthy for me to reproduce here).

Comment: Why is there a $S^T$ in the equation if $S$ is symmetric?

Comment: fair enough; I have deleted the transpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These matrix equations are called *Lyapunov equations* and are extensively studied in control theory.

For instance, if $A$ is Hurwitz (all eigenvalues in the left half-plane), then the unique symmetric solution of $A^TX+XA+Q$ is
$$
X=\int_0^\infty e^{A^T t } Q e^{At} dt.
$$

Comment: could you please point me to a reference for the above result? thanks!

Comment: Check page 230 of http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/mct.html (there is a full version of the book available online on the page). The proof is not complicated.